# WordPress sticky php side bar while scrolling up and down

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress which has a right sidebar. I want it sticky while scrolling up and down. I have given some css style. It is sticky now. But, problem it is shifting it's position from right to left.

Here is my sidebar.php

```
<div class="sidebarsticky col-md-4">

<?php // Select The Widgets

include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/search.php';

if ( is_home()) { //  For Home Page
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/calendar.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/featured.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/comments.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/popular.php';

} elseif ( is_single()) { // For Single Page
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/popular.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/featured.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';

} elseif ( is_category()) { // For Category Page
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/featured.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';

} elseif ( is_tag()) { // For Tag Page
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/featured.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';

} elseif ( is_archive()) { // For Archive Page
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/calendar.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/popular.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/featured.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';

} elseif ( is_page('gsearch')) { // For Search Page
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';

} else { // All The Other Pages
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/300x600_side.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/calendar.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/latest.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/fb.php';
    include ABSPATH.'/wp-content/ads/side_3rdparty.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/comments.php';
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/newsletter.php';
}

// include TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/sidebar/tabs.php';
?>
</div>
```

CSS Style that I have used :-

```
.sidebarsticky {
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: did you try `float: right` ? What about the style shown on firebug ? is it overwritten ?

Comment: Yes, tried. Not overwritten. Style is there. But, don't know it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to stick to the right side, change your style to.

```
.sidebarsticky {
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

`left:0` will force sidebar to be at left rather then right side of the screen. `right:0` will help you out.